# How do I search/replace symbolic links?

Tags: unix, filesystems, path, symbolic-link

I've been having this issue for a long time, and I don't want to reinstall the whole system, yet.

Now there's an app that runs on Java, and it doesn't even open.
The logs says some cocoa files were not found, and the paths DON'T begin with Volumes/

Again, the same issue I had time ago. The previous issue I fixed it by completely re-creating the little applescript that was failing.

Currently, my Dreamweaver CS4 still tries to open files in browser and failing because they lack the Volumes/ at the beginning of the path (local paths)

I'm wondering wether just replacing (or creating) the existing symlinks or just adding some in strategic places so important directories are found would fix the issue… without the need to re-install the OS.

Another user had the SAME exact error, and in his case his Macintosh HD was renamed to Macintosh HD-1. That's it. but his logs shown the below paths with Volumes/
As you can see the logs below don't have it.

Symlinks should fix that, right? (instead of search-replacing all the paths without Volumes/)

```
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]  [LaunchRunner Error] org.rubyforge.rawr.Main.main(String[]) threw an exception:
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]  org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) cannot link Java class org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display, probable missing dependency: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      no swt-cocoa-3740 in java.library.path
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      no swt-cocoa in java.library.path
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      Can't load library: /Users/sergio/libswt-cocoa-3740.jnilib
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      Can't load library: /Users/sergio/libswt-cocoa.jnilib
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaUtilities.get_proxy_or_package_under_package(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:54)
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      at (Anonymous).method_missing(file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/Java/lib/java/jruby-complete.jar!/builtin/javasupport/java.rb:51)
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      at swt_wrapper.Widgets(src/swt_wrapper.rb:28)
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      at swt_wrapper.Swt(src/swt_wrapper.rb:23)
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      at swt_wrapper.(root)(src/swt_wrapper.rb:19)
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033)
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      at main.(root)(src/main.rb:12)
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033)
9/9/12 11:37:37 AM  [0x0-0x3c04c01].compass[24163]      at (Anonymous).(root)(<script>:1)
```

Comment: symlinks should fix it, yes.